# improve or shorten sql query select Result on table [Date]

Tags: sql, select

I have a table of Date and a column of ID,FromDate and ToDate shown at below

```
ID    FromDate                  ToDate
--    --------------            --------------
1     2013-06-10 00:00:00       2013-06-30 00:00:00
2     2013-05-10 00:00:00       2013-06-10 00:00:00
3     2012-08-01 00:00:00       2012-12-31 00:00:00
4     2013-07-10 00:00:00       2013-07-30 00:00:00
```

I doing a checking query and make a column as Result  whether is active, inactive or expired by using [getdate] shown at below

```
Select ID, FromDate, ToDate,
       (case when convert(varchar(8),FromDate,112) <= convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112)
                  and convert(varchar(8),ToDate,112) <= convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) then 'Expired'       
             when convert(varchar(8),FromDate,112) <= convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112)
                  and convert(varchar(8),ToDate,112) >= convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) then 'Active'
             when convert(varchar(8),FromDate,112) >= convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) 
                  and convert(varchar(8),ToDate,112) >= convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) then 'Inactive' end )'Result'
from Date
```

It will show the correct result

```
ID    FromDate                  ToDate                 Result
--    --------------            --------------         -------- 
1     2013-06-10 00:00:00       2013-06-30 00:00:00    Active
2     2013-05-10 00:00:00       2013-06-10 00:00:00    Expired
3     2012-08-01 00:00:00       2012-12-31 00:00:00    Expired
4     2013-07-10 00:00:00       2013-07-30 00:00:00    Inactive
```

But my Case query is too long, is there anyway to shorten the code or improve the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the query:

```
Select 
    ID, 
    FromDate, 
    ToDate,
    (case when convert(varchar(8),ToDate,112) <= convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) then 'Expired'       
        when convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) between convert(varchar(8),FromDate,112) and convert(varchar(8),ToDate,112) then 'Active'
        when convert(varchar(8),FromDate,112) >= convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) then 'Inactive' end )'Result'
from Date
```

Given ToDate is greater than FromDate.

Comment: It work nicely, upvote 1st then later accept answer if no further answer

Comment: You can optimize this by replacing the last when clause with an else :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, FromDate, ToDate,
    CASE WHEN ToDateStr <= NowStr THEN 'Expired'
         WHEN NowStr BETWEEN FromDateStr AND ToDateStr THEN 'Active'
         ELSE 'Inactive' END AS Result
FROM (
SELECT 
    ID, FromDate, ToDate, 
    CONVERT(varchar(8),FromDate,112) AS FromDateStr,
    CONVERT(varchar(8),ToDate,112) AS ToDateStr,
    CONVERT(varchar(8),getdate(),112) AS NowStr
FROM Date) A
```

Given that the From date is always lower or equal than the To Date

Comment: thank but I it will run slower if i doing the join in the query because of subquery. And i do check by using client statistics to compare the 1st answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, fromDate, toDate,
case 
    when daysFromStart > 0 AND daysToEnd > 0 then 'Active'
    when daysFromStart > 0 AND daysToEnd < 0 then 'Expired'
    when daysFromStart < 0 AND daysToEnd > 0 then 'Inactive'
end
from  
(
select 
    id, fromDate, toDate, 
    DATEDIFF(day, fromDate, getdate()) as daysFromStart, 
    DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), toDate) as daysToEnd 
from orders
) t
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7db7/1)